# Most efficient way to merge all .asc files to avoid memoryerror

Tags: python, numpy

Most efficient way to merge all .asc files to avoid memoryerror.

```
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_1.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_2.asc
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_3.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_4.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_5.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_6.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_7.asc 
gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_30_sec_8.asc
```

My code to merge it.

```py
import numpy as np


ascii_grid = [i for i in range(8)]
for i in range(8):
    print("Iteration: " + str(i))
    ascii_grid[i] = np.loadtxt("data/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_30_sec_" + str(i+1) + ".asc", skiprows=6)

first_line = np.hstack(ascii_grid[:4])
second_line = np.hstack(ascii_grid[4:8])
whole_world = np.vstack((first_line, second_line))

np.savez("gpw_data.npz", whole_world)

print("Finish saving")
```

The error

```
PS D:\Python\population_count> python .\process_data.py
Iteration: 0
Iteration: 1
Iteration: 2
Iteration: 3
Iteration: 4
Iteration: 5
Iteration: 6
Iteration: 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\population_count\process_data.py", line 10, in <module>
    second_line = np.hstack(ascii_grid[4:8])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in hstack
  File "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 345, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.48 GiB for an array with shape (10800, 43200) and data type float64
```

What are the solutions to avoid the errors?

Answer (score 3):

My usual approach is to create a VRT using `gdalbuildvrt` and then convert that to a compressed, tiled GeoTiff.

```
gdalbuildvrt -a_srs epsg:27700 lidar.vrt tq*.asc
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" lidar.vrt lidar.tif
gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL -r average lidar.tif 2 4 8 16
```